# Sessions in JavaScript or Global variables

Tags: javascript, html

What do you recommend to use as "website sessions settings": I have few notifications (about using my web site functions) and I show them to user when he open the page first time. However, I do not want to show him everytime that he navigates the page.

My idea is to use some variable that is valid through session on my web site and terminates when user leaves it. 
I am thinking of using php server settings and then use AJAX to set them, but it looks a little complicated. What do you think? Client session settings (if such exist) or global variables, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so.
You can achieve that using HTML and Javascript using a cookie. (Take a look at [jQuery Cookie])[1](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Check for the cookie when the user opens the page; if not found, show him the message and create the cookie.